# Looping through pages using Iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

```js
function changeIframeSrc(index){

   var iframeid = document.getElementByID('changingIframe');
   iframeid.setAttribute('src', sourceList[index]);

 }

var i = 0;
var sourceList = ['111.php', '222.php', '333.php'];

setInterval(function(){ changeIframeSrc(i++); 
// loop properly
if(i == sourceList.length){ i = 0; }
}, 10000);
```

```html
<iframe id="changingIframe" src="" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="87%"></iframe>
```

```
<html>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

        <iframe id="111" src="111.php" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>
        <iframe id="222" src="222.php" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>
        <iframe id="333" src="333.php" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>        

        <iframe id="bottom_banner" src="bottom_banner.php" scrolling="no" width="100%"></iframe>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want my page to change between pages 111,222,333 on a loop every 10 seconds.
I could use   etc. on each page but my banner keeps duplicating on each loop. (therefore stacking up)

I want to keep my banner at the bottom at all times. I want my pages to take up 80% of the height and the banner to take up the 20% left over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Javascript/jQuery to change the source of the iframe that keeps changing source

So

```
 function changeIframeSrc(index){

   var iframeid = document.getElementById('changingIframe');
   iframeid.setAttribute('src', sourceList[index]);

 }
```

and then

```
var i = 0;
var sourceList = ['111.php', '222.php', '333.php', etc];

setInterval(function(){ changeIframeSrc(i++); 
// loop properly
if(i == sourceList.length){ i = 0; }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: and just add this - <iframe id="changingIframe" src="" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="87%"></iframe>

Comment: Yes, sorry I should've stated that

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function --- I get this error

Comment: still get - Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByID is not a function ... See snipped

Comment: @user5554551 Tired-eyes from me, should be getElementById (lowercase d)